DB2 Usage of two combined columns in 'IN' operator
I want to write a SQL statement with in operator over two columns, but I keep getting this SQL error:

[Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.28.11

My SQL condition looks like this:
AND 
    (SELECT car.id1
     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMM1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT car.id2
     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMM1) IN (SELECT inn_car.id
                               FROM....
                              )


The "IN" operator needs either a scalar, or a single-row on its left , but your query tries to use more than 1 row to the left of the "IN" operator.   Either use ..AND (car.id1 in (subquery) OR car.id2 in (subquery))... , or rewrite with other valid syntax.
